# Owl Carousel inside Updatepanel Disappear After Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, owl-carousel

I have repeater control to show something.

```
<div class="owl-carousel trend" style="height:20px;">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptThing" runat="server" DataSourceID="yyy">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEtiket" runat="server" OnClick="lnkEtiket_Click">go</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

It's inside of an updatepanel. No problem on page load but when onClik it disappears. I know it about ajax & jquery issue but I couldn't solve problem. I tried so many examples. Here is my jquery

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    var owltrend = $('.trend');
    owltrend.owlCarousel({
        margin: 5,
        loop: true,
        startPosition: 0,
        lazyLoad: true,
        rtl: false,
        nav: false,
        autoWidth: true,
    });
</script>
```

Note: Its owl carousel 2

Comment: I guess you have to re-initialise the carousel (i.e. run that code again) after the updatepanel returns its data, because by doing an update you destroyed the HTML it was previously attached to and replaced it with a new set of HTML. Or you could move it outside the updatePanel, if it doesn't need to be within it.

Comment: it has to be inside updatepanel. I tried put it in  "function pageLoad(sender, args)" but nothing changed. how can I reinit it ? I'am not good at jquery

Comment: "How can I re-init it". List for the event which tells you the updatePanel has finished. Then run the same code again which you used to initialise the carousel in the first place. You can wrap it in a function to make it re-usable, same as you would with any code. I think the answer just posted below has got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger the jQuery binding again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        createCarousel();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        createCarousel();
    });

    function createCarousel() {
        var owltrend = $('.trend');
        owltrend.owlCarousel({
            margin: 5,
            loop: true,
            startPosition: 0,
            lazyLoad: true,
            rtl: false,
            nav: false,
            autoWidth: true,

        });
    }
</script>
```

`prm.add_endRequest` is triggered when the UpdatePanel is done loading.