# Select2 DropDownList Functionality Disappearing after selection of an item in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, jquery-select2, postback

I have a gridview and a dropdownlist inside the gridview to select items. Because my items list is large, I'm using JQuery Select2 plugin for search. so I've added the references and initialization code in the site master page and also succeeded in initializing the select2 functionality for the first time. however after I select the first item, the dropdown becomes normal dropdown and loses all select2 functionality.

I'm using AdminLTE 3 template's select2 plugin in my asp.net web application with sql as database.

References & Initialization Code in the master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/select2/select2.min.css"/>
<script src="plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()
  })
</script>
```

DropDownList:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="drpItemname" runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="form-control select2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetItemDetails" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
   <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Screenshot after first page load:
[image: screen 1]

Screenshot after Item is selected:
[image: screen 2]

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472613/owl-carousel-inside-updatepanel-disappear-after-postback. Just change "carousel" to "select2"

Comment: that is odd, kindly press "F12" to open dev tools, and see if select2 js and css is always loading.

Comment: Yes for the first time it loads but not the next time

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787491/select2-plugin-inside-gridview-works-with-only-last-row-of-grid-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this code

```
<script>
$(function () {
                $(".select2").select2();
            });
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            $(function () {
                $(".select2").select2();
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

prm.add_endRequest is triggered when the UpdatePanel is done loading.