# Asp button disable and data-loading-text function execute once only

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I would like to disable the asp button, change label while in process.

I included the 'data-loading-text' property to that button and add a jquery script to perform the necessary requirements (the asp button is enclosed within an UpdatePanel control). The code went well on the first execution but on the next attempts, nothing happens (disable and change label won't work)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="showError" runat="server" visible="false" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" style="color:red" runat="server" Text="May Error!" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
        <!-- Button -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                <asp:Button ID="btnReview" runat="server" data-loading-text="Checking ..." class="btn btn-success" Text="Review" OnClick="btnReview_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('#<%=btnReview.ClientID%>').on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.button('loading');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.button('reset');
                }, 8000);
            });
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Looking forward to your kind response.
Thank you.

Comment: Place the script outside the UpdatePanel. Then do as the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473058/5836671