# How to implement input checkbox's checked action?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox, hidden-field

In a WebForm I have an `input checkbox` to which I wanna apply server side action. 
For example, when the checkbox is checked, I want to change some label's text.
I have tried to use on client side:

```
<input id="auto" name="auto" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="AUTOMAT" data-off="MANUAL" <%= string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["auto"]) ? string.Empty : "checked" %> />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>   
<asp:HiddenField ID="customSwitch1Change" runat="server" Value="0" />
        <script>
            $('#auto').click(function () {
                $('#<%=customSwitch1Change.ClientID%>').val("1");
                $('#form1').submit();
            });
        </script>
```

I have used [this](https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css) and [this](https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js) for the input checkbox.

On the server-side I have tried:

```
protected void CustomSwitch1Change(string auto)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auto))
    {
        Label3.Text = $"customSwitch1 was not checked.";
    }
    else
    {
        Label3.Text = $"customSwitch1 was checked and the check value is {auto}.";
    }
}
```

But what I've tried is not working.
What I'm doing wrong? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why not use an `asp:CheckBox` control with the `OnCheckedChange` event?

Comment: Because I want to use this kind of tools. Like: http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the HiddenField. If you change the jQuery to the code below it will do a form post on CheckBox change.

```
<script>
    $('#auto').change(function () {
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Then you can simply get the value in code behind with

```
string auto = Request.Form["auto"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't understand where string auto = Request.Form["auto"]; should fit in C#.

Comment: It is the value of the `auto` checkbox on form post when it's checled. So you can use that to validate the state.

Comment: And how could I use it?
if(auto==?)
  Label3.Text="Some text"; What "?" should be replaced with?

Comment: It's what the value property is `<input id="auto" value="1"` or `<input id="auto" value="true"`

Comment: This value is changing whether the input is checked or not? Or it's a static value (true or false)?

Comment: If the checkbox is not checked, the `value` will not be posted so the string would be empty.

Comment: It works. I still have a problem. If I put the input in an UpdatePanel, the inpus isn't displayed anymore. Any idea how could I use it in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but if you use jQuery on elements in an UpdatePanel, you need to rebind the jQuery to the elements after a PostBack. See example https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473058/5836671\. Just replace carousel code with yours.

Comment: I have put my input in an UpdatePanel so I don't refresh the entire page when the input is checked/unchecked. I also have put my script code instead of the carousel code, but with no success.

Comment: Even if you put in in an UpdatePanel, you still need to rebind jQuery.

Comment: I did it using the example from your link. But it's not working. The input isn't displayed when the page loads.